# Cи: Сортировка qsort и вычисление позиции отсортированных элементов

Tags: c, qsort

В Си я сортирую массив ссылок на изначальный массив с помощью qsort и получаю отсортированный, а потом хочу вычислить позиции новых ссылок относительно старого массива и вывести позиции отсортированных элементов. Для этого я вычисляю позицию вычитаю из новой ссылки на элемент ссылку на начало. Я получаю нужный результат, но у меня сомнение по поводу правильности моего метода из-за большого количества warning.

```
warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast] printf(" %d", ((int)*(pVal+3)-(int)(values))/sizeof(int) );
```

Можно ли это сделать изящнее? Спасибо

> 

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int values[] = { 88, 56, 100, 2, 25 };
int** pVal[5];

int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b) {
   return ( **(int**)a - **(int**)b );
}

int main () {

   for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        pVal[i] = values + i;

   int n;
   printf("Before sorting: \n");
   for( n = 0 ; n < 5; n++ ) {
     printf("%d ", *pVal[n]);
   }

   qsort(pVal, 5, sizeof(int*), cmpfunc);

   printf("\nAfter sorting: \n");
   for( n = 0 ; n < 5; n++ ) 
      printf("%d ", *pVal[n]);

   printf("\nCalculation of sorted elements in the initial array: \n");
   printf("%d", ((int)*(pVal)-(int)(values))/sizeof(int) );
   printf(" %d", ((int)*(pVal+1)-(int)(values))/sizeof(int) );
   printf(" %d", ((int)*(pVal+2)-(int)(values))/sizeof(int) );
   printf(" %d", ((int)*(pVal+3)-(int)(values))/sizeof(int) );
   printf(" %d", ((int)*(pVal+4)-(int)(values))/sizeof(int) );

   return(0);
}
```

**Result**

```
Before sorting: 
88 56 100 2 25 
After sorting: 
2 25 56 88 100 
Position sorted elements in the initial array: 
3 4 1 0 2
```

Comment: Скорее всего вы собираете модуль под x64, а int у вас 32-битный.

Answer (score 0):

Идея правильная, но реализация - нет.

Сразу же видна грубая ошибка

```
int values[] = { 88, 56, 100, 2, 25 };
int** pVal[5];
...
for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     pVal[i] = values + i;
```

С чего это вдруг `pVal` объявлен как массив `int **`, когда, согласно вашей же идее, вам нужен массив `int *`? Компилятор вам ясно указал на эту ошибку в этом цикле, но вы почему-то даже не упоминаете ее в вопросе.

Если вы исправите эту ошибку, то далее вам поможет обычная адресная арифметика. Т.е. вычитать друг из друга нужно сами указатели и только после этого приводить результат к `int`

```
printf(" %d", (int) (*(pVal+1) - values) );
```

Делить при этом результат на `sizeof(int)` не нужно.

Более того, если вы воспользуетесь правильным форматом в `printf`, то и приведение к `int` не понадобится

```
printf(" %td", *(pVal+1) - values);
```

Также непонятно, зачем вы вдруг здесь переключаетесь на синтаксис `*(pVal+1)`, когда в остальном коде пользовались "человеческим" синтаксисом `pVal[1]`

```
printf(" %td", pVal[1] - values);
```

Вот и все.

---

Также, в общем случае сравнение значений типа `int` путем вычитания их друг из друга, как у вас в `cmpfunc` - грубый антипаттерн. Так не делают.

```
int cmpfunc(const void * pa, const void * pb) 
{
  int a = **(const int **) pa, b = **(const int **) pb;
  return (a > b) - (a < b);
}
```

Comment: А слона-то я и не приметил. По поводу cmpfunc тоже понял. Пишут ведь, что вычитание при больших числах может не сработать. Спасибо.

Comment: А почему антипаттерн? Если есть уверенность что абсолютная величина числа меньше чем 2^30?